# How to restrict the users from accessing the admin pages in nodejs application?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ejs

I have created a Ecommerce application using nodejs and ejs. I have admin pages to add and delete the products. How can i hide those pages from the users and show only shop page?

Comment: For that you've to implement the access control in nodeJs. RBAC (Role Based Access Control) provide authorization of your resources. So that admin can access the resource and user can't. Have the look at this [ https://blog.nodeswat.com/implement-access-control-in-node-js-8567e7b484d1 ]

Comment: thanks for your valuable reply narendhran @Narendhran